# Resolve shared_ptr symbol lookup error undefined symbol

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr

There is a type definition using **shared_ptr** as follows:

`typedef std::shared_ptr<MyObject> MyObjectPtr;`

There is a library that returns this type from a method:

`MyObjectPtr p = myLibrary->getMyObject(1);`

If I call a method on `p` right after initializing it, it works:

`p->getProperty();`

But I try to pass `p` to another method and then call a method on `p`, it doesn't work:

`myMethod(p);`

when the called method is:

```
void myMethod(MyObjectPtr p)
{
    p->getProperty();
}
```

I receive this error:
`symbol lookup error`
`undefined symbol`
`MyProgram::myMethod(std::shared_ptr<MyProgram::MyObject>)`

How can I resolve that error so that I can call the method on `p` after passing it?

Comment: Is the function definition you've posted inside `MyProgram`? If not, then it defines a different function to the one you're trying to call.

Comment: If `myMethod` is declared inside `MyProgram` and defined outside the `MyProrgram`, make sure you add `MyProgram` to the definition. i.e,

`void MyProgram::myMethod(MyObjectPtr p)
{
    p->getProperty();
}`

Comment: @theAlias that fixed it - thanks for helping spot this silly mistake! Want to make that an answer?